# Why did the delete response have no cors header in the webdav server?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, cors, webdav

I want to achieve the CORS about webdav.

My machine have a webdav server and ip addr is 192.168.7.88. I test CORS with the ip of 127.0.0.1.

**my web server config (httpd-dav.conf):**

```
 DavLockDB "/opt/apache/var/DavLock"

 Alias /webdav "/webdav"

 <Location /webdav>
     DAV On

     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://127.0.0.1"
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, MKCOL, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PUT"
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth,  Range, Content-Range, Cache-Control"
     Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "DAV, content-length, Allow"
     Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "36000"

     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "webdav"
     <Limit  COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK>
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         # IP address you allow
         Require valid-user
     </Limit>
 </Location>

 #
 # The following directives disable redirects on non-GET requests for
 # a directory that does not include the trailing slash.  This fixes a 
 # problem with several clients that do not appropriately handle 
 # redirects for folders with DAV methods.
 #
 BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
 BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
 BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
 BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[01234]" redirect-carefully
 BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
 BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
 BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
 BrowserMatch " Konqueror/4" redirect-carefully
```

**Request header - OPTIONS:**

```
Accept          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language zh-cn,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-Me...    DELETE
Connection  keep-alive
Host        192.168.7.88
Origin      http://127.0.0.1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
x-insight   activate
```

**Response header - OPTIONS (STATUS = 200 OK):**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, Range, Content-Range, Cache-Control
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, MKCOL, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Orig... http://127.0.0.1
Access-Control-Expose-Hea... DAV, content-length, Allow
Access-Control-Max-Age       36000
Access-Control-Request-He... Origin, Content-Type
Allow   OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST,DELETE,TRACE,PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,COPY,MOVE,PUT,LOCK,UNLOCK
Connection      Keep-Alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/plain
DAV             1,2, <http://apache.org/dav/propset/fs/1>
Date            Tue, 30 Dec 2014 03:25:53 GMT
Keep-Alive      timeout=5, max=99
MS-Author-Via   DAV
Server          Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.5.15
```

**Request Header - DELETE:**

```
Accept           text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding  gzip, deflate
Accept-Language  zh-cn,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Host        192.168.7.88

Origin      http://127.0.0.1
Referer     http://127.0.0.1/webdavtest
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
x-insight   activate
```

**Response Header - DELETE: (STATUS = 204 No Content)**

```
Connection      Keep-Alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/plain
Date            Tue, 30 Dec 2014 01:26:31 GMT
Keep-Alive      timeout=5, max=98
Server          Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.5.15
```

But firefox said :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.7.88/webdav/b.txt. 
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I know the delete response had not cors header, so firefox said these.

**Why did the delete response have no cors header?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of Apache that implements [the RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5).

This is more or less the same kind of issue described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491419/apache-ignoring-php-headers-when-sending-a-304).